# Need a better regex for group matching

Tags: regex

Presently I'm using two regx:

```
ABC.*1EFG

ABC.*2HIJ
```

to retrieve Line 1 and Line 2 from a text file. Is there a better single regex, so that both the lines(L1 and L2) from below can be matched.

```
Line 1: ABCanystring1EFGanystring

Line 2: ABCanystring2HIJanystring

Line 3: ABCanystring2LMNanystring

.

.


.
Line n
```

Thanks you in advance,

Su

Comment: Do you want them matched as individual lines or as a pair in that order only?

Comment: What regex package are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this pattern: `ABC.*(1EFG|2HIJ)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the whole line, you can use `^ABC\s*(1EFG|2HIJ).*$`